# Copy data from one database to another in DB2

Tags: db2

How can one copy data from one database to another database in DB2...?

In Oracle one can do this by creating database links as below

create public database link remote using 'orcl222'

where orcl222 is the source database

```
INSERT INTO test_rowid (ID, NAME)
SELECT ID, NAME    
FROM rsext.test_rowid@remote
```

Can someone please tell me how can i do this in DB2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use several methods:

- Export / LOAD or IMPORT
- Use federation to create a wrapper and a nickname, and then just perform an insert select. (Needs special license)
- Writing an external Stored Procedure (C or Java) that connects to the remote database.

Comment: How can i use federation method...please explain in detail...?

Comment: Here is a detailed description of how one sets up federation between two DB2 databases: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/db2luwtechsupport/entry/how_to_setup_federation_between_two_db2_luw_databases2?lang=en

Comment: Homogeneous federation (i.e. federation between DB2 databases) is included with DB2 (including DB2 Express-C), so it doesn't require an extra license.